# How to simulate http_archive from local file

Tags: bazel

I have main project that implements bazel rule and subproject that simulates end user experience. In subproject I'd like to load archive that is created in the main project, as if it is loaded using http_archive. Here's repo setup example:

```
root/
|- WORKSPACE
|- BUILD
|- rules.bzl
\- integration-tests/
   |- WORKSPACE
   |- BUILD
```

The `root/BUILD` file has `:release` target which creates tar.gz file. I would like to load this file inside `integration-tests/WORKSPACE` as if it is loaded using [http_archive](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive). Is there a way to do this?

---

Simplest way I've found is to use:

```
http_archive(
    urls = [
        "file://path_to_archive",
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Strictly speaking, no, there is not a way to do this. Repository rules like `http_archive` are executed during the [loading phase](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#phases-of-a-build) of a build, while build outputs are created during the [execution phase](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#execution-phase). A repository rule cannot depend on a build target, since that target won't have been built yet.

This is true even and especially across workspace boundaries. There is no way for your sub-project's `WORKSPACE` to directly depend on a build target from the parent project, or any other project.

In this case, I'd think about whether you actually need to load the release tarball in the `WORKSPACE`. Is the tarball actually a Bazel repository? If so, you might want to look into [techniques for testing Bazel extensions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/testing.html).

Comment: Thank you. Is the tarball actually a Bazel repository? - yes I'm trying to write bazel extension and would like to have integration test for that.

Comment: Yes, the tarball for an `http_repository` must be a Bazel repository. Not sure if this is helpful but here's the "best practices" for testing new rules: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.6.0/skylark/deploying.html#testing

Comment: Nice I'm reading deployment best practices, it is really helpful. Just noticed that in practice `deps.bzl` is used instead of `repositories.bzl`. Unless I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

You can [override dependencies on the command line](https://bazel.build/docs/external#overriding-repositories), and use a local checkout of a repository instead of the `http_archive`.

For example, given the following `WORKSPACE.bazel`

```
workspace(name = "cli_cpp")

# Group the sources of the library so that CMake rule have access to it
all_content = """filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])"""

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
   name = "qpid-cpp",
   build_file_content = all_content,
   strip_prefix = "qpid-cpp-main",
   url = "https://github.com/apache/qpid-cpp/archive/main.zip",
)
```

You can checkout the `qpid-cpp` repository, or download and unzip that archive, make your changes in it, add an empty `WORKSPACE.bazel` file and also add the following `BUILD.bazel` there

```
filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**/*"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

Now, run Bazel with

```
--override_repository=qpid-cpp=/path/to/qpid-cpp
```